# How can I perform a boolean 'AND' search in Delphi using 'Find in Files?

Tags: regex, delphi, search

Now that my code is getting ever larger, a strategy to locate key code locations is more important. With faster PC's now, 'Search' 'Find in Files' is quick and effective - 'Search all files in project' often does not work if you have used implicit units. I've struggled to understand regular expressions but presumably they would let me do a search like:

one OR two

one AND two

All searches are required to be on the same line.

This would be a great improvement on a simple keyword search. Is this possible in Delphi's search? I'm using XE, XE2 and D7 (sometimes).

Comment: which edition of Delphi?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regular expression you need to search for `one` or `two` is

```
one|two
```

The `|` symbol means `or` in regex speak.

Searching for a file containing both `one` and `two` is more difficult since the search is line-oriented. You could search for `one` and `two` on the same line like this:

```
one.*two|two.*one
```

Comment: Thanks David. Its a shame that the OR is so complex because that's often the most useful construct.